# UITapGestureRecognizer is not opening url

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an action when tapping an image to open an URL in navigator but when I tap on it, nothing opens up. This is my code:

```
@IBAction func Anuncio(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://capturando.es/") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check once `yourImagename.userInteractionEnabled  = true` or `false` if it is false just enable once thereafter all other functions are automatically triggered

```
yourImagename.userInteractionEnabled  = true
```

Comment: That was my problem! Thanks!

Comment: I will but I have to wait for several minutes ;)